# How to run c program using GCC not using clang in mac

Tags: macos, gcc, clang, apple-m1, gcc-warning

When I check the version of clang

```
❯ clang --version
Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin22.3.0
```

when I check the version of gcc

```
❯ gcc --version
Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin22.3.0
```

Here I am not able to use the gcc compiler that I installed using homebrew

```
❯ ls -l /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  15 kumar  admin  480 Feb  5 20:30 12.2.0
```

Please tell me how can I use the gcc(installed using Homebrew) for running any c program.

When I compile any program by writing `gcc hello.c` ,Then it is similar to `clang hello.c`  Whereas I want to compile the file `hello.c` with the gcc that is installed using homebrew at `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't *"run"* any program using `gcc`, you can only compile and link using `gcc`.

Your shell determines which program to run according to your PATH. If your PATH contains `/usr/bin` before `/opt/homebrew/bin` then you will be running Apple's `gcc` rather than the **homebrew** one. You can check your PATH with:

```
echo $PATH
```

You can check which `gcc` will be run when you type `gcc` without a path by running:

```
type gcc
```

---

Pretty much all **homebrew** packages link their binaries into `/opt/homebrew/bin`, so firstly you should set your PATH like this:

```
export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:PATH
```

That makes your shell look for **homebrew** packages *before* Apple ones. You should do that in your login profile so it is set every time you login.

Then you need to check what name your **homebrew** GCC package has installed `gcc` under, it might be `gcc-10` or `gcc-11`. You can check with:

```
ls /opt/homebrew/bin/gcc*
```

If it is `gcc-11`, you would compile with:

```
gcc-11 -o prog program.c
```

Note that if your code is C++, you will need:

```
g++-11 -o prog program.cpp
```